# Automorphisms of $\mathbb F(t) / \mathbb F$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $\mathbb F$ be some field and $\mathbb F(t)$ the field of one-variable rational functions with coefficients in $\mathbb F$. Let $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb F$ such that $ad-bc\neq0$. Show there exists a unique map $\sigma:\mathbb F(t) \rightarrow \mathbb F(t)$ with $\sigma\in Aut(\mathbb F(t) / \mathbb F)$ that satisfies:
$$\sigma(t)=\frac{at+c}{bt+d}$$

I'm pretty confused as to who's who and what goes where... What $\sigma$ does is it takes a rational function, and sends it to another rational function, such that if $f$ is this rational function, then $\sigma(f)$ is again a rational function. But it seems like we are already given this function... Am I missing something?

If not, the next step is to show that it is an automorphism, starting with showing that for every rational function the above expression is indeed rational, which is easy enough.

But then it gets confusing. If I take the above equation condition and plug in functions instead of the parameter $t$, then this won't be a homomorphism, since $\sigma(1)=\frac{a+c}{b+d}\neq1$ So how can this condition be satisfied? Could it be that the condition is actually not for functionals but for the function $f(t)=t$ as the argument for $\sigma$? And if so, how can one show this automorphism?

Thanks

Comment: This automorphism fixes the elements of $\mathbb{F}$. It only moves the indeterminate term $t$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The automorphism $\sigma$ takes $t$ to
$$\sigma(t)=\frac{at+c}{bt+d}.$$
It takes a typical rational function $g(t)$ to $g(\sigma (t))$, that is
$$\sigma(g(t))=g\left(\frac{at+c}{bt+d}\right).$$

To show it's an automorphism, try finding a formula for its inverse.

Comment: Ooohhh that was so rediculously simple! It makes perfect sense, and now homomorphism is straightforward (also finding inverse is trivial). Thank you.